Summon Battlefield: Attacking your own minions for benefit?
This was a boss I've made for my players that ended up very different from anything from the community I've seen thus far so I decided to post it here and ask if this is all RAW proper so that players outside my table know whether or not they can do this.
Intended Mechanics. The strategy involves Summoning Hordes of PL 1 Unfriendly Minions and using Takedown feat with the following text (or Takedown 2 if its a close attack).

If you render a minion incapacitated with an attack, you get an immediate extra attack as a free action against another minion within range and adjacent to the previous target’s location. The extra attack is with the same attack and bonus as the first. You can continue using this advantage until you miss or there are no more minions within range of your attack or your last target. (pg. 140)

Since this is a free action, we can destroy all of these minions that we'll likely have around 100 or so in stock of since Summon PL 1 is cheap when you add Check Required DC 20+ and/or the Weakened Trait. What we do thereafter is add a corpse explosion style effect via giving the attacks a Area Rank lower than the Damage effect's PL, as listed with Rocket Launchers (pg. 219) or Telekinetic Column (pg. 84), and allow this character to hit the real enemies while defeating the minions!
Intended Narrative. You are a haunted one, constantly chased by the evil of someone seeking vengeance towards you and marked for death as their undying minions chase you to the ends of the earth, often appearing to prevent you from doing the good you've trained your life to do. In defiance, you've grown accustomed to combating them as you combating enemies, using them as cover for cleaves, becoming resistant to their attacks, becoming strong or equip enough to attack multiple enemies at a time as you rush through the swarm to fight the opponents you face in front of you. Ex. Guts from Berserk, Doomslayer from Doom.
Potential Problems. The action economy for players is pretty crazy as you can throw several AoEs at opponents in a single turn, so for typical campaigns that don't use Triggered as seen in this post here probably don't force players into this narrative to get this level of action economy.

I can't tell what you're trying top do here. Is this using easy-to-hit mooks to get attacks on harder-to-hit enemies? If so, you need to spell out what you're trying to do exactly, because whether that's actually advantageous depends very strongly on what exactly you're doing (IIRC, only contagion is worthwhile).

Updated the text to increase clarity.

I think you have a valid question as to whether this is valid as RAW, so I have voted to reopen.

I would say that your "Intended Narrative" feels like it doesn't add anything if you're just looking for a rules interpretation.

Intended Narrative was there so that people would know why the ruling was useful though maybe it didn't need to be listed in that order.

Hmm, and just now found that I'd answered a very similar question like this before at https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99537/how-many-extra-actions-can-you-gain-with-takedown?rq=1

From a technical standpoint, there's nothing incorrect about your interpretation if the GM (which I believe is you) is fine with running the game that way. Takedown has no text indicating that the attack must be one with an attack roll, merely that you must have rendered a minion incapacitated with an attack, and that your next target must be a minion with the same attack and bonus. Using Area Attacks, I suspect you probably will want to spring for the second rank of Takedown, since there's a decent change that there will not be another living minion adjacent to the target.
I personally think that this is against the spirit of the rules, but you have noted in the past that you are only interested in the letter of the rules. And, as with prior caveats because Rule 0 is a listed rule, nothing obligates a GM to allow for such a tactic by the letter or spirit of the rules.

The attack does have a attack roll. It's like rocket launchers where there's a attack roll, and a AoE with a lower rank.

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken: And Takedown doesn't even require a roll, although it does refer to an attack bonus in the text. Like I said, you're on the windy side of the law from a technical point, even if it's not how I'd roll.
